# How to loopback usb microphone to default output in Alsa?

Tags: debian, audio, xfce, alsa, microphone

Given a Debian Stretch + Xfce system with Alsa, i would like to hear my USB microphone in my headphones. I cannot find any option to do so natively with graphical alsa mixers like Volti or [QasTools](http://xwmw.org/qastools/applications.html).

The problem seems to be that in both mixers the USB microphone is detected as a separate audio card and this somehow does not allow them to redirect its signal into the default motherboard card (Intel HDA) to which my headphones are attached. Or at least, they don't seem to present any option to do so, unless i'm missing something. Perhaps QasConfig or QasHctl allow advanced options that allow such?

I'm also trying to avoid pavucontrol.

Comment: If you use Pulseaudio, without `pavucontrol`: `pacmd load-module module-loopback ...`. If you use ALSA only: `alsaloop` (won't work when Pulseaudio is running).

Comment: @dirkt The [alsaloop command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/alsaloop.1.html) looks neat. I tried `alsaloop -C hw:2,0 -P hw:0,0 -t 50000 -d` which does what i want but as it is running i can't hear anymore the sounds coming from the PC itself. For example, VLC complains that the device 'default' is busy and watching youtube videos yields no audio.

Comment: Use `plughw` instead of `hw` (put `dmix` etc. plugins in front).

Comment: @dirkt Ok i tried `alsaloop -C plughw:2,0 -P plughw:0,0 -t 50000` and various combinations of `hw` and `plughw` but still complains... [There are](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116042) [various](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181922) [discussions](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147208) online but can't figure out anything certain for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alsaloop` to loopback an input device to an output device.

To use this together with other applications, a quick summary of ALSA configuration:

ALSA is configured in the per-user `~/.asoundrc` or in the system-wide `/etc/asound.conf`. That's what you see in QasConfig, but to avoid surprises, better look at the files directly. If the existing setup doesn't work for you, you need to create or modify `~/.asoundrc`.

Information about the "plugins" you can use to configure ALSA is e.g. [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html). The `hw` devices usually just allow one single application to read/write to them. To allow multiple applications to do that, you use `dmix` or `dsnoop`. `plughw` automates that by putting a number of plugins in front of `hw`.

`QasHctl` just shows the mixer (or any hardware-related control) settings that are also available with `alsamixer` or `amixer`.

So:

1) Make sure Pulseaudio is not running (`ps axu`). Really sure. Pulseaudio uses ALSA to access the hardware.

Now configure `~/.asoundrc`:

2) Put a `dmix` in front of your output device(s).

3) Put a `dsnoop` in front of your input device(s).

These two should normally have been made available automatically, check `aplay -L` or `QasConfig`. If they are already present, use those.

4) If your `default` device was set to the `pulse` plugin, remove it -- that's the Pulseaudio compatability layer.

5) Set `default` to one of the `dmix` devices you just created (or `plughw` to use the automatically created ones).

If you've trouble configuring everything, edit question with output of `cat /proc/asound/pcm` so I can see your hardware, with the original `~/.asoundrc` (if present) and the one you tried to make, and I'll have a look.