# How to capture sound from default built in speaker and microphone together using ALSA

Tags: alsa

I wrote my C++ application, it opens an audio capture device (built in microphone on laptop) and records audio from it using ALSA library.

But I also want to mix it with audio from the speaker (if another application is playing music, I want to mix my microphone audio with it).

I think I am trying to do something opposite of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375290/how-to-loopback-usb-microphone-to-default-output-in-alsa).

I tried following instructions [here](https://www.sdrutah.org/info/high_rate_loopback_websdr.html) but am confused.

I think I need to use dmix and dsnoop and create some loop device, but I have no idea what these are or how to do it.

If someone can provide an example .asoundrc file or show me how to read the audio from speaker and mix it with my mic, that would be great. I don't think I need c++ code for this, its probably configuring some text file somewhere.

I also want to understand how it works. It seems like a simple thing to do, but is driving me nuts. Thanks!

Note: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66226760) is what I need? But some explanation would be nice